# What is behind the transformation of list and set things?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, set

When solving the set questions of Hackerank, I got this doubt. When I ran the first snippet, I got the type as a list, Which is correct because of the outside braces([]).

```
n = [set(input().split()) for _ in range(1)]
print(type(n))
```

But During the Second snippet, the type of f is a set.

```
f,e=[set(input().split()) for _ in range(2)]
print(type(f))
```

What is behind the transformation of list and set things?? Even though the f had [] braces, how was it considered set?? Then why this did not happen for n??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second code, this is list unpacking. For example:

```
    a, b = [1, 2]
    print(a)
    print(type(a))
    print(b)
    print(type(b))
```